# Excel : How to find how many times some numbers appears

Tags: excel, bigdata

I have data for 20 customers and their purchases for one year (all product names). I want to find the top 10 products that were bought more by all customers. But the product names (Item IDS) are infinite. How can I do something like count if for infinitely different names?[image: I am just sending you a part of excel to have a "picture" of the problem.]

Comment: Countif() or countifs() will count names, so create a list of unique names: unique() can do that or make a copy of the name column and remove duplicates.

Comment: okeyy that was a good start. now for every customer I have about 250 unique products he has bought. how do I apply the count if for each of them? By hand it is impossible.

Comment: If you set the function up correctly (such that it works on ranges, then just drag down.

Comment: There are not an infinite number of products, just a lot. Your picture does not describe anything.

Comment: Solar Mike you are right I just did not think in count if to select the area to look for and then the cell number instead of the number itself. Indeed when I did drag down it worked. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Davesexcel The image was merely indicative to realize that the products are separate and the concept of infinity was non-literal obviously. Βut you are right I forgot the (" ") in the word infinity my bad .